# cocoapodsのプラットフォームをiOS7以降にすると出るエラーについて

Tags: ios, cocoapods

現在cocoapodsを利用してライブラリを導入しているのですが、podfileのプラットフォームをiOS7もしくはiOS8にすると以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-            0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:13:in `report': incompatible     character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:58:in `report_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:300:in `handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:274:in `rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:264:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:45:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/bin/pod:43:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

このエラーはどのような意味なのでしょうか？
ちなみにポッドファイルは以下のようになっております。

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'YLMoment', '~> 0.2.0'
pod 'RegexKitLite', '4.0'
pod 'AFDropdownNotification', '~> 1.0'
pod 'RESideMenu', '~> 4.0.7'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちょっと不思議な現象だと思ったので、私もOSXシステム標準のRubyでCocoaPods0.35.0を使い、調べてみました。

`incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`は、ファイルに全角文字列が入っている場合に起きるRubyのエラーです。

```
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
```

となっている箇所に、シングルクオートではなくアポストロフィが入っています。
正しくはこうなります。

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

Comment: 解決しました！本当にありがとうございます！